# TSQL Help | The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see my query below, I have counted the columns a number of times and also I have checked the commas, they seem to be fine but I keep on getting the error

The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

```
DECLARE @StatusValues TABLE (StatusId INT,StatusText VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(1,'Code 1 - Entered E&D Waiver');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(2,'Code 2 - Nursing Facility');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(3,'Code 3 - Entered Assisted Living Waiver');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(4,'Code 4 - Entered TBI/SCI Waiver');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(5,'Code 5 - Entered IL Waiver');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(6,'Code 6 - DECEASED');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(7,'Code 7 - Refused Waiver Services');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(8,'Code 8 - Other (Explain)');
INSERT INTO @StatusValues VALUES(NULL,'Please select');


INSERT INTO SWMPDD.dbo.Clients(
    AdditionalPertinent,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    ApplicationApprovedBy,
    ByWhom,
    City,
    ClientAt,
    ContactPerson,
    ContactPhone,
    County,
    DateClientContacted,
    Diagnostic,
    Diet,
    Direction,
    DateOfBirth,
    Email,
    FirstName,
    Gender,
    InOtherCase,
    InTakeDate,
    IPAddress,
    LastName,
    LastUpdateUser,
    LastUpdateTime,
    LockinStatus,
    Medicaid,
    Medicare,
    MethodofContact,
    MiddleInitial,
    OfficalComments,
    OtherComments,
    ParticipantId,
    ParticipantSignature,
    PersonResidenceCode,
    Phone,
    Physician,
    PhysicianAddress,
    PhysicianCity,
    PhysicianPhone,
    PhysicianZip,
    CreationDate,
    ReferralPhone,
    ReferralSoruce,
    RelationshipToClient,
    SignatureDate,
    SSN,
    [State],
    CreationUser,
    VerificationDate,
    VerificationOfMedicaidStatus,
    Zip,
    ClientId,
    StatusId,
    StatusText
)
SELECT 
    AdditionalPertinent,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    ApplicationApprovedBy,
    ByWhom,
    City,
    ClientAt,
    ContactPerson,
    ContactPhone,
    county,
    DateClientContacted,
    Diagnostic,
    Diet,
    Direction,
    DOB,
    EmailAddress,
    FirstName,
    Gender,
    InOtherCase,
    InTakeDate,
    ipaddress,
    LastName,
    lastUpdatedBy,
    lastupdatedDate,
    LockinStatus,
    Medicaid,
    Medicare,
    MethodofContact,
    MiddleInit,
    OfficalComments,
    OtherComments,
    ParticipantId,
    ParticipantSignature,
    PersonResidenceCode,
    phone,
    Physician,
    PhysicianAddress,
    PhysicianCity,
    PhysicianPhone
    PhysicianZip,
    recDate,
    ReferralPhone,
    ReferralSoruce,
    RelationshiptoClient,
    SignatureDate,
    SSN,
    [state],
    userid,
    VerificationDate,
    VerificationofMedicaidStatus,
    zip,
    NEWID(),
    (SELECT StatusId FROM @StatusValues WHERE StatusText = ReasonforRemovalCode) abc,
    Code8Other
FROM msdepart.dbo.tblParticipant;
```

Answer (score 30):

Your list of fields in the SELECT portion and INSERT (..column list..) is out by 1 because of a missing comma here:

```
PhysicianPhone
PhysicianZip,
```

In the SELECT.  It is aliasing Phone as Zip, and everything else falls out of step.

Comment: thanks a lot, and I thought I had checked all the commas. :D

Comment: too a while and a few passes :)